# Force use extension from required namespace

Tags: c#, extension-methods

```
namespace common
{
   public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static string stringextmethod(this string uri)
        {

        }
   }
}

namespace commonCore
{
   public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static string stringextmethod(this string uri)
        {

        }
   }
}
```

I have a class that refer both namespaces above, now when I try to use 'stringextmethod' I am getting an error 'Overload resolution failed..'
How can I use extension method 'stringextmethod' from 'common' namespace only.

Comment: You could only use `Using Common` and avoid `Using commonCore` in the relevant code files.

Comment: relavant code has huge functionality and refers both namespaces, so is there any way that I can use 'Using' at specific required statement.

Comment: You could call the extension method directly and include the namespace in the call like `common.stringextmethod(whatever)` instead of using it as an extension.

Comment: @Jens He has to include the class name... `common.MyExtensions.stringextmethod(whatever)`

Comment: @xanatos true, somehow missed that, but the base idea, to call the method as a function with proper qualification, instead of as an extension was still valid ;-)

Comment: @Jens Yep... If you want to be cruel, you could even create your own extension method in your "current" namespace that uses one of the two extension methods :-) "current" namespace should triumph over "external" namespace collisions (that is the solution proposed here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18702605/613130)