# Resolve CS0121 in System.Web.Http

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

This code:

```
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.PartialContent);
```

Yields following compilation error:

> Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage,
>   System.Net.HttpStatusCode)' and
>   'System.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessageCommonExtensions.CreateResponse(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage,
>   System.Net.HttpStatusCode)'

Both are in `System.Net.Http` namespace, one in `System.Web.Http` assembly the other in `System.Net.Http.Formatting` but I need them both as a reference. Even worse `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions` class is present in both assemblies.

As a workaround, I could use this overload, which seems to be in only one of them:

```
Request.CreateResponse<object>(HttpStatusCode.PartialContent, null);
```

But is there any other way to resolve the conflict?

*[Steps to reproduce]*

1. Create a console app
2. Add the reference to `System.Net.Http`
3. Add the reference to `System.Net.Http.Formatting` from NuGet
4. Add `using System.Net.Http`
5. Add `var req = new HttpRequestMessage();`
6. Try adding `req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);`
7. You should see 12 extension method overloads. *Some are duplicated, those are the problem.*

Comment: VS easily handle this, as I know

Comment: @demo well, it looks not to be able. Anyway, the solution should not be IDE dependant, but rather pure code or config. You can fully qualify a class to resolve conflict, but what can you do with extension methods that are imported from any used namespace unattended?

Comment: If it's saying its ambiguous then you just have to make it clear.  Use the full namespace of the one that you do want to use.

Comment: @Archer please give an example of how to do that in case of an extension method.

Comment: Can you give a **[MCVE]** so we can copy/paste & reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Archer No, as you need at least three separate assemblies to reproduce. If they were in my code, would not be an issue, but these are BCL. Anyway, the situation is somewhat similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283583/extension-methods-conflict but with the difference, that I can't change the BCL.

Comment: Okay - if you can't tell us how to reproduce it then I can't help you.  Good luck :)

Comment: @Archer I have added the steps, see update.

Comment: I've just duplicated your steps and have no problem, so something else is causing the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you can use extension methods directly to resolve such ambiguities:

Instead of

```
myRequest.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.PartialContent);
```

use

```
HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse(myRequest, HttpStatusCode.PartialContent);
```

---

In this specific case, I could not reproduce the issue following your instructions. However, I have downloaded the [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/) instead of the [System.Net.Http.Formatting Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Formatting) since the later one is marked as deprecated. Maybe try to update to the newer Nuget?

Update: I can reproduce the issue when also installing the [System.Web.Http.Common Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Web.Http.Common/) and adding `using System.Web.Http;` to the file. Using the explicit call to the method as shown above resolves the issue.

Comment: Just to make it more challenging, explicit call gives: `CS0433 The type 'HttpRequestMessageExtensions' exists in both 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'`. Unfortunatelly, I can't get rid of `System.Net.Http.Formatting` as it comes with a dependency too.  But still looks promising.

Comment: But it works in the other way around: `HttpRequestMessageCommonExtensions.CreateResponse` is unambiguous. I have come to this approach before, but I thought that there is something better. Well, thank you for confirming that there isn't.